# WooCommerce - Setting every shipping price to 0 if amount is bigger then x (I have a 90% working snippet but can't modify)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I found a snippet which is almost perfect and I feel so silly but can't modify it to fit my needs..

What it makes:

```
if price is above 10--> shipping cost 4.5
if price is under 10--> shipping cost 2.5
```

What I need:

```
if price is above 10000--> shipping cost 0 (and display 0 next to each shipping method if it's not too hard)
if price is under 10000 --> keep original pricing set in WooCommerce settings
```

Thank you very much if you could help me out! Have a very nice day!

https://reigelgallarde.me/programming/woocommerce-shipping-fee-changes-condition-met/

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'woocommerce_package_rates', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_package_rates( $rates, $package ) {

    $new_cost = ( WC()->cart->subtotal < 10 ) ? 4.5 : 2.5;

    foreach($rates as $key => $rate ) {
        $rates[$key]->cost = $new_cost;
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

Comment: _“if price is under 100000”_ - do you actually mean 100,000 here, or just 10,000? If the former, you are not making much sense, because 15,000 would fulfill _both_ conditions. And what is your actual problem with modifying the given code accordingly?

Comment: _“keep original pricing set in WooCommerce settings”_ - and in this place, do you mean _pricing_ (actual product price) or _shipping cost_?

Comment: Hi Misorude, sorry for my mistake. 
- I mean 10.000 (above 10.000 every shipping cost method costs 0)
- if total cart is under 10.000 then no changes should be made to the shipping costs (//so it would display the original prices which I have set in WooCommerce settings, so no changes needed)

Thank you very much if you have any idea, I feel hopeless. Have a very nice day!

Comment: So use a simple `if` to check your condition, and if it is fulfilled, set the cost to 0 for all rates in a foreach loop. If not - simply do nothing …

Comment: Yeah, I am really debil to not know how to do this, I understand this and it's a shame I know. My developer has disappeared, and all I need just this one thing to have my first site finished. Thank you for your response, I will try to combine the things you said, however I know nothing about php. I appreciate your time and thank you very much for your comments. You helped me a lot I think. Have a very nice day :-)

Comment: If you replace the function body with `if( WC()->cart->subtotal > 10000) { foreach($rates as $key => $rate) { $rates[$key]->cost = 0; } } return $rates;`, that should probably do it.

Comment: Lol, it seems that i made it based on your instructions :O I have to test it but seems promising for the first sight... Thank you very much man!!!!!

add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'woocommerce_package_rates', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_package_rates( $rates, $package ) {

If WC()->cart->subtotal > 10000    
$new_cost =0;

    foreach($rates as $key => $rate ) {
        $rates[$key]->cost = $new_cost;
    }

    return $rates;
}

Comment: Yeah, I made that way! (not exactly but similar) Misorude, you are a genius! Seems working!Thanks!!!!!:D